# Swift - Skip Returning value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

This is my piece of code

```
let ids = self.mapView.annotations.map({ (annotation) -> String? in
        if !annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
            let customAnnotation = annotation as! CustomAnnotation
                return customAnnotation.id!
            }
            return nil
        })

print(ids)
```

I am using CustomAnnotation which has a property called `id`. I just want to put all the `id`s in an array ignoring `userLocation`. But the above snippet prints

```
["eqdiv13bei", "31esdc332e", nil, "2dxcd23d"]
```

When the condition is not satisfied, I do not want to return anything. Here, I am forced to return `nil`.

How could I avoid returning `nil` to get the result `["eqdiv13bei", "31esdc332e", "2dxcd23d"]`?

Comment: Add a .filter{$0 != nil} - the linked thing won't actually work as .flatMap requires a multidimensional array.

Comment: @sschale: I am fairly sure that it works, the given example in the link operates on a one-dimensional array as well. (There are several flatMap methods.)